# In-App Purchase Apple - Is it possible to block entire store unless the customer purchase the subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

Maybe it's a dumb question but couldn't find anything stating something close to this quesiton in apple guidelines. So basically we have a client who wants to block their e-commece store compltely to everyone unless they purchase a subscription using in-app purchases! My question is simple is this possible or is going to get rejected by Apple.
The majority of the apps give extra features and don't block the entire app... but for example netfilx even tho it doesn't use in-app purchases currently block the entire usability to the people who don't buy their service.

I've tried to check the apple guidelines but didn't find any information revelant to this quesiton!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Your question is outside the scope for this site.